# Why does stripe charge not show as "refunded" when retrieved with python stripe lib?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I issued a refund manually in a stripe account (in test mode), the payment now shows as `refunded` and exists in the refunded tab of the seller dashboard.

[image]

I wanted to programmatically distinguish if a charge has been refunded or not using the python stripe sdk, e.g.

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

charge_response = stripe.Charge.retrieve(
  "ch_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
)

charge_response['refunded']
>> False
```

However when I do this, object that is returned has `refunded: False` even after waiting a week.

Why is that?

Comment: Hi, first I'd recommend not sharing your Stripe keys publicly, even your test keys pose some risk. I'd generate a new key ASAP: https://stripe.com/docs/keys#revoking-keys. It's hard to say for certain why the refunded property is False for you there. One thing to note is that that property will remain False unless a full refund has been granted (not just a partial one). From your screenshot that doesn't look to be the case. I'd double check that the charge ID you are passing in is correct and perhaps printing the entire charge_response. I would also review the associated charge.refunded event.

Comment: @ttmarek key is just the one from the stripe docs. Also this was a full refund over a week ago

Comment: @ttmarek yeah It's a good point about the IDs. On the dashboard I notice you don't get a charge ID you get `py_XXXXXXXXXXXXX` vs the charge object which has `ch_YYYYYYYYYYYYYY`   I am correlating them by amount and date, since I don't have many transactions on that test account

But I don't know any way to get the charge via this `py_...` ID from the charges api, or anyway to check for sure it's the same object?

Comment: Just a heads-up that the secret key in the Stripe docs _is_ your secret key. When you are logged-in to you Stripe account, the docs automatically pull in your test keys to make it easy for you to copy-paste the code examples.

Comment: Interesting thanks, I didn't know that. But in this case it's just a throw away account. I'll edit it out anyway.

Comment: @ttmarek I think your idea about the IDs might be on the right track. Any further comments on that? If the dashboard just had these things as `py_` how do I get the charge id there? or vice versa how from the charges API do I find the `py_...` id?

Comment: So, the approach would be to retrieve the balance_transaction using https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/retrieve. The balance_transaction ID should be available on the py_'s object under that same property name (it will look like txn_xyz). When retrieving the balance transaction you will want to expand the `source.source_transfer`. And the source_transfer will have a `source_transaction` which will point to the charge. More on expand here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to go the opposite direction however? I'm actually starting with a charge (ch_ object) and want to get to the payment (py_ object)